# Multiple Intent Filters

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, android-manifest

I have an intent filter setup where it can receive Action.send (using this for adobe share button) and Action.view (using this for preview email attachments) 
The issue I am having is when I try to share a pdf from adobe to my app, it defaults as Action view.     If I remove action.view from the manifest it then send the PDF to my app with Action Send.    The code fails when using action view.....it only works with action send

Or Maybe I am better of asking how do I handle this for both a preview or adobe
This work great for hitting the preview button on an email but not the share button in adobe

```
   Uri pdfUri = (Uri) getIntent().getData();
                PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfUri.getPath());
```

Actual Code:

```
if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action) && type != null) {

            Uri pdfUri = (Uri) getIntent().getData();
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfUri.getPath());
            //PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfUri.getPath());

            try {
                //Intent intent = Intent();
                //


                //PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader

(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ File.separatorChar + 

"Anthonyrules.pdf");

                PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader,
                        new FileOutputStream

(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ File.separatorChar + 

"anthonyrulesmodified.pdf"));

                Image image = Image.getInstance

(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ File.separatorChar + 

"temp.jpg");

                for(int i=1; i<= pdfReader.getNumberOfPages(); i++){

                    //put content under
                    PdfContentByte content = pdfStamper.getUnderContent(i);
                    image.setAbsolutePosition(100f, 150f);
                    image.scaleToFit(100, 125);
                    content.addImage(image);

                    //put content over
                    //content = pdfStamper.getOverContent(i);
                    //image.setAbsolutePosition(100f, 150f);
                    //image.scaleToFit(100,125);
                    //content.addImage(image);



                    mSubjectEditText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_subject);
                    mSubjectEditText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_subject);







                    //Text over the existing page
                    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA,
                            BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
                    content.beginText();
                    content.setFontAndSize(bf, 18);

                    //content.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, "Page No: " + i, 130, 

15, 0);
                    content.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, 

mSubjectEditText.getText().toString(),150, 120, 0);
                    content.endText();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Completed", 

Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                pdfStamper.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (CharSequence) e, 

Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e("error", String.valueOf(e));
            } catch (DocumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (CharSequence) e, 

Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e("error document", String.valueOf(e));
            }

        }
```

My Trunicated Manifest File

```
<intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out further up in my code was `intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);`

This was forcing the intent type

Answer (score 2):

You need to have two intent filter tags in manifest, as its two different configurations.

```
<intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: No, that does nothing different.  Tried that